# DELETE from table based on output of large complex query with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the following query in order to delete its output from the main table, but it does not seem to be working

```
DELETE B 
FROM database1.dbo.myTable B
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  S.VERSION
               ,S.PRODUCT
               ,S.CUSTOMER
               ,S.CCYYMM
               ,S.DIRECTOR
               ,S.MANAGER
               ,S.TEAM
               ,S.FORECAST_TYPE
               ,S.FORECAST_FINAL
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  PRODUCT
                   ,ISNULL(CUSTOMER,'`') AS CUSTOMER
                   ,DIRECTOR
                   ,MANAGER
                   ,TEAM
                   ,FORECAST_TYPE
                   ,FORECAST_FINAL
                   ,VERSION
                   ,CCYYMM
            FROM database1.dbo.myTable
            WHERE VERSION = 'VR1'
            AND LEFT(CCYYMM, 4) IN (YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1, YEAR(GETDATE()) + 2, YEAR(GETDATE()) + 3)
        ) S
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  PRODUCT
                   ,CCYYMM
                   ,ISNULL(CUSTOMER,'`') AS CUSTOMER
            FROM database2.dbo.otherTable
            WHERE LEFT(CCYYMM, 4) = YEAR(GETDATE())
        ) T
        ON S.[PRODUCT] = T.[PRODUCT] AND S.CUSTOMER = T.CUSTOMER
        WHERE T.CUSTOMER IS NULL
        AND S.CUSTOMER IS NOT NULL 
    ) A
    WHERE A.CUSTOMER NOT LIKE '%CustomerA%'
    AND A.TOP_CUST NOT LIKE '%Growth Expanse%'
    AND A.TOP_CUST NOT LIKE '%Divine Solution%'
    AND A.TOP_CUST NOT LIKE '%Weather People%'
)
```

The table I am trying to delete the output from `(database1.dbo.myTable)` doesn't have a key, so I am not sure if that is the issue, or if I need to include all the columns in the original SELECT statement that matches the table? When I tried to see the number of records from this query by doing

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM database1.dbo.myTable B
WHERE EXISTS (query from above)
```

It gave me way more records than the actual output of the query, so I don't think that's right, but I am not sure how to delete the output of this query from the table

Comment: That subquery isn't correlated; I suspect that is the problem.

Comment: Also, you reuse the alias `A` in your query when they share the same scope; a very poor idea. I initially thought that `(A.CUSTOMER NOT LIKE '%CustomerA%')` was referencing the table you want to `DELETE` from, but it's actually referencing the subquery of the same alias. (Also, you don't need to wrap each clause in your `WHERE` in parentheses (`()`).)

Comment: `WHERE LEFT(DATE, 4) = YEAR(GETDATE())` has a code "smell" to it as well. How can a column called `DATE` (which is presumably a date and time value) have 4 left characters? Date and time values are a binary value, it doesn't make sense to use string functions against it. Why are you not using date boundaries?

Comment: your basic problem, is that for every row the server will check if a row exixts(sebquery) whivh should be true for every column or none

Comment: Thanks everyone I've edited the question to make a bit more sense, most of these problems are from me changing the actual names from the original database, the date is actually in the form CCYYMM as a string, thats why I used the LEFT field.

Comment: How would I correlate the subequery then? and it checks if every row in the subquery and relates it back to the regular table?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it, there was a lot of unnecessary nonsense I had before that was able to solve with a CTE

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    PRODUCT,
    ISNULL(CUSTOMER, '`') AS CUSTOMER
  FROM
    database2.dbo.otherTable
  WHERE
    LEFT(CCYYMM, 4) = YEAR(GETDATE())
)
DELETE SBF
FROM
  database1.dbo.myTable AS SBF
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE AS RP
    ON RP.[PRODUCT] = SBF.[PRODUCT]
    AND RP.CUSTOMER = ISNULL(SBF.CUSTOMER, '`')
WHERE
  SBF.VERSION = 'VR1'
  AND LEFT(SBF.CCYYMM, 4) IN (
    YEAR(GETDATE()),
    YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1,
    YEAR(GETDATE()) + 2,
    YEAR(GETDATE()) + 3
  )
  AND ISNULL(SBF.CUSTOMER, '`') NOT LIKE '%CustomerA%'
  AND ISNULL(SBF.CUSTOMER, '`') NOT LIKE '%Growth Expanse%'
  AND ISNULL(SBF.CUSTOMER, '`') NOT LIKE '%Divine Solution%'
  AND ISNULL(SBF.CUSTOMER, '`') NOT LIKE '%Weather People%'
  AND RP.CUSTOMER IS NULL
```